# what's the difference PHP-FPM , Opcache and APC

Tags: php, nginx

i use nginx with Fast CGI cache settings , it's working great but i read all around the internet about OPcache and APC . 
i don't understand the difference between them and FPM and why do people use them when cache with FPM is much easier just adding few sentences to nginx conf .
i use these setting for reference

```
fastcgi_cache microcache;
fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 302 1d;
fastcgi_cache_valid 400 500 504 404 1m;
```

if anyone can explain in details the differences .